# Minus value in top is not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Following css does not work in IE 8.

```
content: ' ';  
position: absolute;  
left: 0px;
top: -10px; //--- this is not working in IE.
```

The component disappears in IE. while in other browsers this works fine.

---

The wrapping div css:

```
clear: both;
margin: 0px auto;
width: 350px;
position: relative;
```

Comment: Can you build a JSFiddle example please? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: its impossible to guess that without seeing more code, especially wrapping element's code. Jsfiddle would make it so much easier to solve.

Comment: What happens if you add `overflow: visible` to the wrapper?

Comment: @Pekka: Nothing changed.

Comment: Needs more info. As said, a JSFiddle example would be ideal.

Comment: Seems to work for me in IE8 (I see the triangle above the box). Maybe it's the doctype as thirtydot suggests?

Comment: Yeah it may be DOCTYPE.. if i change my IE settings to Quirks mode it goes to hell :-) Be aware that if you have some code before the DOCTYPE tag, IE changes to Quirks mode automatically. This can be easily verified in IE developer toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your fiddle:

You are adding `div` inside a `form`. Try taking `div` outside of `form` tag. May be you have some `form` css that is causing this.

---

And ***the fiddle you have posted works fine on IE 8 at my side.***

Answer (score 0):

2 possible solutions without seeing more of the code:

1. the surrounding div doesn't have it's position set to a value like relative
2. have you tried setting the z-index of the element to a higher value?

can't post a comment yet so posting it as an answer

Comment: I have added wrapping div css in question. Take a look.